# Examples of automorphisms on structures

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

For some structure $(M,I)$ with $M$ a set and $I$ the interpretation of the constants, functions, and predicates, what is an example of a such a structure such that for each $a$ of $M$ there are only finitely many $b$ in $M$ such that there is an automorphisms $f$ of $\mathcal{m}$ such that $f(a) = b$, but there are uncountably many automorphisms of $\mathcal{m}$.

Geometrically, I've been told to think of a "complete binary tree" as such a structure. But why? How could one write it in the form above? What about $(R,*)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The complete binary tree is a nice example. Use the binary predicate symbol $M(x,y)$, where $M(x,y)$ holds if $x$ is the mother (immediate predecessor) of $y$. Any automorphism has to preserve level, and for any $a$ there are only finitely many $b$ at the same level as $a$.

Answer (score 3):

An equivalence relation on an infinite set $M$ having exactly one equivalence class of cardinality $n$ for each positive integer $n$, and no infinite equivalence class.

Comment: Very clean example.

Comment: I don't see how $(\mathbb{R}, *)$ would fulfill this then

Comment: So what? What is $(\mathbb R,*)$ and what does it have to do with my answer? I suppose $\mathbb R$ is the real line, but what is $*$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's multiplication, it was part of the original question

Comment: The semigroup $(\mathbb R,*)$ is **not** an example of what you're looking for. The mappings $f_n(x)=x^{2n+1}$ (for $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$) are automorphisms, and the element $a=2$ is mapped to infinitely many different elements $b=2,2^3,2^5,\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

The example $(\mathbb Z,R)$ where $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z:|x|\lt|y|\}$ is best possible, in the sense that the orbit $\{f(a):f\text{ is an automorphism}\}$ has cardinality at most $2$ for each $a$.